# Reset the values on Modal box on reload

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Reset the values on Modal box on reload

```
<div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header custom-modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
               Create Job Vaccination
            </h4>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal Body -->
         <form name="vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm" class="form-inline" >
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 150px">
               <div class="row ">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-12"  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningType.$invalid && (vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningType.$dirty || vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningType.$touched) }">
                     <label for="regId" class="col-md-6">Screening Type:</label>
                     <span class="col-md-6">
                        <select style="width: 100%;"  
                           ng-model="vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId" 
                           ng-options="sctype.screeningTypeId as sctype.screeningType for sctype in vaccjobctrl.screeningTypeList"
                           class="form-control field-size ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="screeningType"
                           id="screeningType" required>
                           <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                           <option value="{{sctype.screeningTypeId}}">{{sctype.screeningType}}</option>
                        </select>
                     </span>
                     <div class="col-sm-6 error-color"
                        ng-if="vaccjobctrl.interacted(vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningType)"
                        ng-messages="vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.screeningType.$error">
                        <div ng-messages-include="src/common/validation-messages.html"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
               Cancel
               </button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-joli"  ng-click="vaccjobctrl.saveJobVaccination(vaccjobctrl.vacc);" ng-disabled="vaccjobctrl.vaccineForm.$invalid" data-dismiss="modal">
               Create Vaccination
               </button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

this is the modal box.

On click on open Modal this function will be called

```
vm.showModal = function() {
      $('#detailsModal').modal('show');
};
```

values in the select box are pre-populated, on reopening the modal box it show the previously selected values. If trying to clear that the the select box border color changed to red on reopen.

Answer (score 0):

In `Bootstrap 3` you can reset your form after your **modal window** has been closed as follows:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

You can just reset any content manually when modal is hidden.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class='modal-body1'>
          <h3>Close and open, I will be gone!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use:

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body1").html("");
});
```

You can do more like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    $(".modal-body1").html("Where did he go?!?!?!");
  });
});
```

There are more about them in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage.

**UPDATE AS PER YOUR NEED:**

If you want to do it `angular` way, use the **jquery src** above **angularjs source** in `index.html`. You can simply use the `jquery` functions inside the `angularjs` controller.

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnq86/15/

For using document.ready function in angular.

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])

.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
    });
}]);
```

However Creating **directive** is the right way to do it. Follow the link to get some help with creating **directive** to execute `jquery` functions in `angularjs`.

[jquery in angularjs using directive](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html)

Comment: Is there any angular js way of doing this ?

Comment: Normally, when you have to do external script stuffs such as jquery in angular you have to create directive. That is the correct way of doing it. work around is simply inject the jquery source and embed the code in script tag to that page.